# Javafx Deployment Issues

Tags: java, deployment, javafx

I want to deploy javafx application:

It generates the executable file but with following problems:

- I am not able to set the application icon
- I am not able to set the custom .iss file or .wix file for the executable
- Resulting app is installed as Unknown in startup .
- Resulting app is installed on AppData folder of current user not in program files as other applications
- It does not create desktop shortcut.

  With verbose output I get following on console:

  ```
  add package/windows/sample4deploy.ico to the class path to customize)

  add package/windows/sample4deploy.wxs to the class path to customize)

  Using default package resource [Inno Setup project file] (add package/windows/sample4deploy.iss to the class path to customize)

  Using default package resource [setup dialog icon] (add package/windows/sample4deploy-setup-icon.bmp to the class path to customize)
  ```

Following these messages:

I created folder named **package** in root directory of app and in  that windows folder.

So my path package/windows .I added athe resources in that folder such as app icon , .wix file . iss file .

Still it takes the default values

I am not getting what is wrong with it ..

Regards,
Sadiq

Comment: I also have problem, So you reply you question how you resolve each ?(eclipse)

Comment: Any luck installing into Program Files instead of the app data folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your ant path:

In my case, Netbeans->tools->options->java->ant

Added the Folder that contains the "package folder". So that Ant can search for the icon or image.

[image]

Comment: how to update this path in maven ant plugin? I am doing same thing with eclipse and i am using maven ant plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This solves Mubasher's question:

..............
...........

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>

                            <additionalClasspathElements>
                                <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}</additionalClasspathElement>
                            </additionalClasspathElements>
```

...........
.........
........

Comment: Thanks For help.  I did not try your way but I manage to add classpath entry in maven antrun plugin. details here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973919/where-should-i-put-installer-resources-wxs-file-dmg-script-icon-and-how-to-con/26039897#26039897