# where should i put installer resources (wxs file,dmg-script,icon) and how to configure maven antrun when deploying self contained app

Tags: java, oracle, maven, ant, javafx-2

Where should i drop my custom configured WIX installer configuration file and how to configured javafx packger tool in maven based java fx project using antrun plugin? I successfully have made basic MSI installer using default package resource and it is working fine. Now i have configured installers WXS files as fxpackager underlying is using wix toolset when creating MSI.

using this [Customizing MSI installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667061/customizing-msi-installer) and this [How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows) i have manages to add Icon. but deploy task is not picking custom configuration file i.e WXS

I had also read official guide http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html

my project structure looks like this

[image: project structure]

You can see i have added on both locations i.e under java-client/package/windows/*.*
and i also added in src/main/deploy/package/windows/*.* as mentioned on linked questions.
but both ways are not working with my maven ant plugin. my mind is exploding.

From Oracle documentation they states
"
Packaging tools look for customized resources on the class path before reverting to built-in resources. The Java Packager has "." (the current working directory) added to the class path by default. Therefore, to replace the application icon, copy your custom icon to ./package/macosx/DemoApp.icns in the directory from which javapackager is run (typically, the root project directory)."

i also tried to add ${basedir} to ant class-path look at My build part of pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-temp-jar</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
                            <taskdef uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                                classpath="maven.plugin.classpath" />

                            <fx:jar
                                destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-temp">
                                <fx:application id="fxApp" name="${project.name}"
                                    mainClass="${exec.mainClass}" />
                                <fx:fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
                                <manifest>
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${app.vendor}" />
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${app.name}" />
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0" />
                                </manifest>
                            </fx:jar>
                            <attachartifact
                                file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-temp.jar"
                                classifier="temp" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-deployment-bundle</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
                            <property name="windows.basedir" value="${basedir}/src/main/deploy/package/windows" />
                            <property name="mac.basedir" value="${basedir}/package/macosx" />
                            <property name="my.basedir" value="${basedir}" />
                            <taskdef uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                                classpath="${my.basedir}:${windows.basedir}:${mac.basedir}" />

                            <fx:deploy nativeBundles="msi" width="600" height="400"
                                outdir="${dist.dir}" embedJNLP="true" outfile="${project.build.finalName}"
                                verbose="true">
                                <fx:application name="${project.build.finalName}"
                                    mainClass="${exec.mainClass}" />
                                <fx:preferences shortcut="true" menu="true"
                                    install="true" />
                                <fx:resources>
                                    <fx:fileset dir="${project.build.directory}"
                                        includes="${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                                </fx:resources>
                                <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"
                                    copyright="${application.copyright}" description="Test built from Java executable jar">
                                    <fx:icon
                                        href="${basedir}/src/main/deploy/package/windows/${project.build.finalName}.ico" />
                                </fx:info>
                                <fx:platform javafx="${javafx.version}">
                                    <fx:jvmarg value="-Xms512m" />
                                    <fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
                                </fx:platform>
                                <fx:permissions elevated="true" />
                            </fx:deploy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                    <systemPath>${javafx.tools.ant.jar}</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
                    <systemPath>${fx.home}</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <JavaFX-Version>${javafx.version}</JavaFX-Version>
                        <JavaFX-Application-Class>${exec.mainClass}</JavaFX-Application-Class>
                        <Main-Class>com/javafx/main/Main</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can you please please help me figuring out the problam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After so many tries finally i have resolved my issue and for helping others I am posting here the solution.

Project Structure should be like this

[image]

and pom.xml should b like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.client</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaClient</artifactId>
<version>5.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>JavaClient</name>

<properties>
    <exec.mainClass>com.client.MainApp</exec.mainClass>
    <javafx.version>2.2.67</javafx.version>
    <fx.home>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</fx.home>
    <javafx.tools.ant.jar>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</javafx.tools.ant.jar>
    <javafx-dialogs.jar>${project.basedir}/lib/javafx-dialogs-0.0.1.jar</javafx-dialogs.jar>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <dist.dir>${project.build.directory}/deploy</dist.dir>
    <base.dir>${project.basedir}</base.dir>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        <systemPath>${fx.home}</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-dialogs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx-dialogs.jar}</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-temp-jar</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
                            <taskdef uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                                classpath="${project.basedir}:${javafx.tools.ant.jar}:${fx.home}" />

                            <fx:jar
                                destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-temp">
                                <fx:application id="fxApp" name="${project.name}"
                                    mainClass="${exec.mainClass}" />
                                <fx:fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
                                <manifest>
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${app.vendor}" />
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${app.name}" />
                                    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0" />
                                </manifest>
                            </fx:jar>
                            <attachartifact
                                file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-temp.jar"
                                classifier="temp" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-deployment-bundle</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
                            
                            <taskdef uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                                classpath="${project.basedir}:${javafx.tools.ant.jar}:${fx.home}" />

                            <fx:deploy nativeBundles="all" width="100" height="100"
                                outdir="${dist.dir}" embedJNLP="true" outfile="${project.build.finalName}"
                                verbose="true">

                                <fx:application name="${project.build.finalName}"
                                    mainClass="${exec.mainClass}" />
                                <fx:resources>
                                    <fx:fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                                </fx:resources>
                                <fx:info title="${project.build.finalName}" vendor="NUAXIS"
                                    description="Test built from Java executable jar" />

                                <fx:permissions elevated="true" />
                            </fx:deploy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <JavaFX-Version>${javafx.version}</JavaFX-Version>
                        <JavaFX-Application-Class>${exec.mainClass}</JavaFX-Application-Class>
                        <Main-Class>com/javafx/main/Main</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Now I will explain you my mistake. closely look the build part of Question. in ant-run plugin when we go in fx:deploy task here you find that i have entry of class-path. i messed up this part which was so simple. look now in my Pom here. class path now updated. first i mention the base dir then ant-fx-plugin path then jfxrt.jar path. jfxrt may be not necessary. after this i have removed dependencies section of plugin. this is critical. if i do not remove this section then my antrun plugin alwasy look into maven provided dependencies but not in ant-classpath. in ant-classpath order is very very important. your basedir must always come before ant-run.jar . thats it

Hope This will helpful for the persons who will face this issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. Finally got it working after struggling around for hours. My pom.xml with JavaFX 8 is even a little more lightweight: https://github.com/totalvoidness/cryptomator/blob/master/main/ui/pom.xml

Comment: @SebastianS I am happy that it some how helped you. yes at start my POM was large. Now I had removed assembly plugin and just using default javafx jar task and maven dependencies plugin with javafx 8. Share your assembly discripter too if you like that how you achieve without using a jar ant task.

Comment: No I'm still using the maven-antrun-plugin and I also create a jar-with-dependencies, as I want a single runnable jar file anyway. For those interested, I posted the link above. But it doesn't add anything new, that qualifies it as an alternative answer to your question.